# Php Unlink with relative path isnt working

Tags: php, unlink

I Want to unlink a file. There are hundreds of post about this but I cant seem to get it to work.

I execute my script from:

```
public_html/dev/admin/delete.php
```

The file Im trying to delete is at:

```
public_html/dev/admin/upload/picture.jpeg
```

The code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT url FROM news WHERE id='$id'";

    $result = db::get_instance()->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unlink($row['url']);
      }
    }
```

The content of row url = `upload/picture.jpeg`

Now why isnt this working. Php documentation says relative pads are fine to use if im right?

EDIT:

So I found out if I hardcode the url it works:

```
unlink('upload/picture.jpeg');
```

But when I use the following it doesnt:

```
unlink($row[url]);
```

But `echo ($row[url]);` prints: `upload/picture.jpeg`

Can it be so that $row[url] is not a string or something?

Comment: Can it be permissions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Comment: I edited my post with some new info. I really dont have a cleu whats going on!

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a typo in your paths? or do you really have a public_html and a public**k**_html folder?

Comment: That was a typo in the post. But it is not in my code. I use a relative pad and the public_html folder isnt included in that. It was more an example of where the documents I am working in are placed.

Comment: have you trimmed white-space from the `$row['url']` ?

Answer (score 1):

Oke so `$row['url']` seems to have produced extra white spaces in the url.

A simple `trim($row['url'])` fixed it!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$row['url']` path is correct and file have correct permission.

Comment: I updated some info to my post. hardcode the url does work but printing the row doesnt. while the info is exact the same..

Answer (score 0):

It is a very, very good idea to always use file system routines with the absolute path so that there can be no "relative" mistakes. Deleting the wrong file in the wrong folder can be costly!

So, prepend each filesystem link with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and possibly hardcode or use `getcwd()` to get the current directory (usually the directory the PHP file is in).

giving you:

```
// remove potential double slashes in complete address.
// Also add trailing slash before the $row
 $currentWD = ltrim(getcwd(),"/")."/";

 unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$currentWD.$row['url']);
```

Where :

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == "home/public_html/"
getcwd() == "/dev/admin"
$row['url'] == "upload/picture.jpeg"
```

Please also be aware that on Apache systems (and most others I think) that file system is **CasE SensiTiVe**!!

---

Also please be careful with using quotes around your array keys, you want to have `$row['url']` with the (single) quotes rather than without quotes.

---

**EDIT:**
Some debugs:

- What is `echo getcwd()`? This should be the current folder.
- Is your string correctly character encoded, so that the letters of the filesystem it is looking for are the correct letters rather than cryllic or similar that look the same but are not exactly the same (I know this is obscure but...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference?

```
public_html/dev/admin/upload/picture.png
                                     ^^^

unlink('upload/picture.jpeg');
                       ^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo in my post. I found the solution!